# CF migration from 7 to 8, CF8 crashing due to table lock but other server still on 7 running fine!

Tags: coldfusion, crash, coldfusion-8, performance, coldfusion-7

We are in the process of migrating our 4 production servers from CFMX7 32 bit to CF8 64 bit. After the first server got migrated and with the other still running CFMX7 32bit, we found that the CF8 crashes at times due to table lock but the same area running fine with CFMX7 on other servers.

The tables which get locked usually are by a batchjob which is still on CF7 32bit server.

**Server details:**

```
New server for CF8
   OS : windows 2003 64 bit
      RAM : 4 GB
   Java : 1.6.0_23   64bit
   CF : 8,0,1,195765  

Old servers and batchjob server
   OS : Windows 2003
     RAM : 4 GB
   Java : 1.4.2_09
   CF : 7,0,2,142559
```

Comment: Can you give details of the batch job? And why migrate to 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of your version of CF and the environment, the real problem you have here is the table locking.

If you have a batch job locking a whole table it will cause problems for other processes trying to access that table and as such you should try to fix that as a priority rather than trying to figure out why your older version of CF appears to be avoiding such problems.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Agreed. The server is not the real key your batch job is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing but... it's possible your locking problem is appearing now due to the updated SQLServer JDBC drivers that ship with CF8. Not that i know how.

That said, your probably best off looking at the locking issue directly, as Ciaran suggests.